# Sum of values with in a time range is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a dataset that returns some columns. I am writting a query that will show sum of some rows of two columns TotalQty and TotalValue within a datetime range for each row of another column buyer. That means Total number of rows will be the number of different buyer. But somehow my query is not summing the rows within the datetime range. It is showing all the values of each date. How can I solve this?
I tried this-

```
 Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRPTMonthWiseProductionSummaryFORATL]
@MonthName  Varchar(50) 
-- Exec spRPTMonthWiseProductionSummaryFORATL 'Sep,2014'
AS BEGIN
Declare @FromDate datetime, 
        @ToDate datetime,
        @FromDate2 datetime,
        @FromDate3 datetime,
        @FromDate4 datetime,
        @FromDate5 datetime,
        @FromDate6 datetime
Select @FromDate = Convert(Datetime,@MonthName), 
       @ToDate = DateAdd(d,-1,DateAdd(m,1,Convert(Datetime,@MonthName)))
Select @FromDate2 = DATEADD(M,1,@FromDate)
Select @FromDate3 = DATEADD(M,1,@FromDate2)
Select @FromDate4 = DATEADD(M,1,@FromDate3)
Select @FromDate5 = DATEADD(M,1,@FromDate4)
Select @FromDate6 = DATEADD(M,1,@FromDate5)

Select B.Buyer,
**CASE WHEN UseDate>=@FromDate And UseDate< @FromDate2  
     THEN SUM(TotalQty) END AS m1Qty,
CASE WHEN UseDate>=@FromDate And UseDate< @FromDate2  
     THEN SUM(TotalValue) END AS m1Value,  
CASE WHEN UseDate>=@FromDate2 And UseDate< @FromDate3  
     THEN SUM(TotalQty) END AS m2Qty,
CASE WHEN UseDate>=@FromDate2 And UseDate< @FromDate3  
     THEN SUM(TotalValue) END AS m2Value,  
CASE WHEN UseDate>=@FromDate3 And UseDate< @FromDate4  
     THEN SUM(TotalQty) END AS m3Qty,
CASE WHEN UseDate>=@FromDate3 And UseDate< @FromDate4  
     THEN SUM(TotalValue) END AS m3Value,  
CASE WHEN UseDate>=@FromDate4 And UseDate< @FromDate5  
     THEN SUM(TotalQty) END AS m4Qty,
CASE WHEN UseDate>=@FromDate4 And UseDate< @FromDate5  
     THEN SUM(TotalValue) END AS m4Value,  
CASE WHEN UseDate>=@FromDate5 And UseDate< @FromDate6  
     THEN SUM(TotalQty) END AS m5Qty,
CASE WHEN UseDate>=@FromDate5 And UseDate< @FromDate6  
     THEN SUM(TotalValue) END AS m5Value**  

from 
(
Select Buyer,
       sum(Unit1Qty)Unit1_Qty ,
       sum(Unit2Qty)Unit2_Qty,      
       sum(Unit3Qty)Unit3_Qty, 
       sum(Unit1Qty*FOB) as Unit1_Value,
       sum(Unit2Qty*FOB) as Unit2_Value,
       sum(Unit3Qty*FOB) as Unit3_Value,
       sum(Unit1Qty*CM) as Unit1_CM,
       sum(Unit2Qty*CM) as Unit2_CM,
       sum(Unit3Qty*CM) as Unit3_CM,
       sum(Unit1Qty) +sum(Unit2Qty)+ sum(Unit3Qty) as TotalQty, 
      sum(Unit1Qty*FOB)+sum(Unit2Qty*FOB) +sum(Unit3Qty*FOB) as TotalValue,
      sum(Unit1Qty*CM) +sum(Unit2Qty*CM) +sum(Unit3Qty*CM) as TotalCM,
      A.UseDate
from 
(
Select C.Name as Buyer,
Unit1Qty = Case When PPC.factoryname ='Unit-1' 
                then OM.OrderQty else 0 end,
Unit2Qty = Case When PPC.factoryname ='Unit-2' 
                then OM.OrderQty else 0 end,
Unit3Qty = Case When PPC.factoryname ='Unit-3' 
                then OM.OrderQty else 0 end,
FOB = 
(Select Rate = 
        Case When Sum(ISNULL(OrderQty,0)) <> 0 
        Then Sum(ISNULL(rate,0)*ISNULL(OrderQty,0))/Sum(ISNULL(OrderQty,0))    
        Else 0 
   End From ExportOrder 
 Where OrderRefID = OM.OrderRefID) ,
--FR.Rate  as FOB,
isnull(CM,0) as CM,LA.UseDate
from AmanProduction.dbo.OrderMaster OM
INNER JOIN AmanProduction.dbo.LineAllocation LA 
ON LA.OrderRef=OM.OrderRefID
INNER JOIN FileRef FR 
ON FR.FileRefID= OM.FileRefID
INNER JOIN SystemManager.dbo.ProductionProcessCostCenter PPC 
ON PPC.CostCenter = LA.Line
INNER JOIN SystemManager.dbo.ProductionProcess PP 
ON PP.ProcessID = PPC.ProcessId
INNER JOIN SystemManager.dbo.Contacts C 
ON C.Code = Om.BuyerCode
LEFT JOIN(Select OC.OrderRefID,Rate as CM 
from AmanProduction.dbo.OrderMasterCostBreakdown OC
INNER JOIN BOMItemGroups BG 
ON BG.BOMItemGroupId = OC.BOMItemGroupId
Where BOMItemGroupDesc ='CM') CM 
ON OM.OrderRefID=CM.OrderRefID 
Where PP.ProcessName ='Sewing' 
and LA.UseDate >=  @FromDate  ) A
Where Unit1Qty>0 or Unit2Qty>0  or Unit3Qty>0 Group by UseDate,Buyer
)B 
Group by year(UseDate),month(UseDate),UseDate,Buyer

End
```

I am getting data like this
[image]

There are so many values for m1qty,m1value, and m2qty,m2value for buyer s.OLIVER. But there should be 1 value of m1qty,m1value and 1 value of m2qty,m2value of "s.Oliver" that is the summation of the date range i specified in case conditions.

Comment: Your query is quite impressive. It would be nice to have some data in order to dig in it.

Comment: updated qs. is it ok?

Comment: @Mimi Highlight your code which you think is not properly working

Comment: @ Khurram Ali the case conditions Are not working

Comment: There are a lot of cases, I would go for simplifying and make it more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure is rather large and it would take some time to understand the complete logic. However, there is one thing that seems likely to be the issue and it is your CASE expressions. They probably should be inside the aggregate function. What I mean is, instead of writing them like this:

```
CASE WHEN UseDate>=@FromDate And UseDate< @FromDate2 THEN SUM(TotalQty) END
```

you should (probably) write them like this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN UseDate>=@FromDate And UseDate< @FromDate2 THEN TotalQty END)
```

and then you should also remove `UseDate` from the GROUP BY (but probably keep both `year(UseDate)` and `month(UseDate)` – again, hard to say without digging deep into the logic).

Answer (score 0):

If I grossly simplify your query, I see something strange in your `group by`.

```
 SELECT B.Buyer
   FROM 
  (
   SELECT Buyer
     FROM 
    (
     SELECT C.Name as Buyer
     FROM ....
    )
  ) B
GROUP BY year(UseDate),month(UseDate),UseDate,Buyer
```

If you want one line per Buyer, why do you not group on Buyer as the highest level?

You would get one line per Buyer if you change your `group by` to

```
GROUP BY Buyer
```

Grouping ion the dates as well will give you several lines per buyer, namely one line per grouped date. Your query seems to want to spread results for different dates over different columns, so no need to group on those.

Actually, you might want to `group by Buyer` earlier on, in one of the inner queries.

Comment: These are comments, aren't they?

Comment: @AndriyM: if the group by is incorrect, it explains the observation of the OP that they get too many lines of results. I should not have asked if the proposed solution works, that is right.

Comment: Well, at least moving the grouping criteria around won't change the results (unless you are grouping with rollup, which the OP isn't), that I can promise you.

Comment: @AndriyML of course not! Thanks. Will edit accordingly!